# How to switch between 2 icons?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm working on a Hugo theme for my site and this theme have the ability to switch from light to a dark mode. I want to change the icon when the theme is in light when the dark mode is activated.

This is the javascipt part of the code:

```
_Blog.toggleTheme = function() {
        const currentTheme = window.localStorage && window.localStorage.getItem('theme')
        const isDark = currentTheme === 'dark'
        $('body').toggleClass('dark-theme', isDark)
        $('.theme-switch').on('click', () => {
            $('body').toggleClass('dark-theme')
            window.localStorage &&
                window.localStorage.setItem('theme', document.body.classList.contains('dark-theme') ? 'dark' : 'light', )
        })
    }
```

and this is the HTML part:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="theme-switch"><i class="iconfont icon-sun"></i></a>&nbsp;
```

What I'm trying to resolve is that when I click on the icon, it changes to another icon. So "icon-sun" on click can become "icon-moon".

Comment: So what is the issue you're having?

Comment: You’re already doing it with `toggleClass(...)`, just add another line

Comment: Could you provide a link to the theme you are using?

Comment: @Andam https://themes.gohugo.io/keepit/

Answer (score 0):

You could just add the `.toggle()` jQuery method to your function or to a seperate click event: `$('.icon-sun, .icon-moon').toggle();` In this case, you will be toggling their visibility. For a smoother toggle you could also use `.fadeToggle()`.

Answer (score 0):

This scripts will do it. add this to one of your script tags. Change icon-facebook to the icon that you want. because i dont think the theme you are working on has icon-moon. if you want to I can show you how to add extra set of icons to the theme.

```
$('.theme-switch').click(function(){
$(this).find("i").toggleClass("icon-sun").toggleClass("icon-facebook");
});
```